# issue related to adding Column with Constraint into existing datatable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a database in SQL Server,  i have following two different queries :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TblUDR
ADD CaregiverId int NULL

alter table tblUDR Add Constraint FK_TblUDR_TblCaregiver 
foreign key (CaregiverId) references dbo.TblCaregiver(Id)
```

Among the two query above, first query adds new column into the table `tblUDR` and second query adds foreign key contraint for added column into first query.

my question is that is it possible to add a new column with foreignkey contraint into single query instead of two different query??

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.TblUDR
 ADD CaregiverId INT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_TblUDR_TblCaregiver REFERENCES dbo.TblCaregiver(Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 separate queries. You can check the syntax of `ALTER TABLE` here: [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).
 It doesn't allow to specify both adding column and constraint in one query.